# How Do You Generate a Report for Number of Mail Clickthroughs and What The Most Popular Links Were For a Campaign

Tags: civimail, civireport, urls, links, tracked-links

Here is the scenario: We send daily news updates, they are all assigned the same campaign. I want to be able to see what was the most clicked URL for a given campaign.

Currently I have to export the mail clickthrough report and use the countif and unique functions in excel but that comes with its challenges.

Is there a built in or extension report that I can build something like this?

Wordpress 6.2 and CiviCRM 5.59

Comment: Have you looked at SearchKit which is fast becoming the answer to many 'is it possible' type questions :-)

Comment: I did - but what would I be searching for? There does not seem to be an option for tracked URLs in emails.

Comment: i really don't know. looks like there are these couple of tables involved: civicrm_mailing_event_trackable_url_open and civicrm_mailing_trackable_url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be possible with SearchKit soon. Mail clicks was just added to APIv4 and SearchKit last week: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/26016

So you won't be able to use it yet, but it will be possible soon.